# Отправить из потока сигнал для анимации

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, анимация, сигналы-слоты

Как с помощью метода `pyqtSignal` отправить сигнал об анимации без ссылки.

Вопрос не много не корректный, хотелось чтобы клик по кнопке фиксировался в потоке и отправлялся сигнал на старт анимации из потока.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Thread(QThread):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()


class Window(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.initUi()
    self.animation()

def initUi(self):

    self.resize(1000, 1000)

    self.button = QPushButton('КНОПКА', self)
    self.button.setGeometry(300, 250, 100, 100)
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.start)

def animation(self):

    self.opacity = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
    self.opacity.setOpacity(0.0)

    self.level2 = QLabel(self)
    self.level2.setText("LABEL")
    self.level2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px")
    self.level2.move(450, 250)
    self.level2.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity)

    self.an = QPropertyAnimation(self.opacity, b"opacity")
    self.an.setDuration(2500)
    self.an.setLoopCount(10)
    self.an.setStartValue(0.0)
    self.an.setEndValue(1.0)

def start(self):

    self.an.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Что значит сигнал об анимации без ссылки?

Comment: Отправить старт через сигнал, а не ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что я вас правильно понял, но чтобы отправить сигнал вам надо:

- объявить сигнал,
- подключить сигнал к слоту и
- испускайте сигнал в нужное вам время и нужном месте.

Обратите внимание, что `connect` для кнопки отключен.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Thread(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal()                            # + объявление сигнала

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.threadSignal.emit()                       # + испускание сигнала
            self.msleep(25200)                            

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()
        self.animation()

        self.thread = Thread()                           
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.start)       # + подключение сигнала
        self.thread.start()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.button = QPushButton('КНОПКА', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(300, 250, 100, 100)
#        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start)           # ---

    def animation(self):
        self.opacity = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.opacity.setOpacity(0.0)
        self.level2 = QLabel(self)
        self.level2.setText("LABEL")
        self.level2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px")
        self.level2.move(450, 250)
        self.level2.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity)
        self.an = QPropertyAnimation(self.opacity, b"opacity")
        self.an.setDuration(2500)
        self.an.setLoopCount(10)
        self.an.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.an.setEndValue(1.0)

    def start(self):
        self.an.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

> Вопрос не много не корректный, хотелось что бы клик по кнопке фиксировался в потоке и отправлялся сигнал на старт анимации из потока.

**Клик по кнопке делаем только в основном потоке!**, а сигнал на старт анимации из созданного потока `self.thread = Thread()`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Thread(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(str)                             # + объявление сигнала

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flagClick = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.flagClick:
                self.threadSignal.emit('')                     # + испускание сигнала
                self.msleep(25200) 
                self.threadSignal.emit('Stop')
                self.flagClick = False                

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()
        self.animation()

        self.thread = Thread()                           
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.start)         # + подключение сигнала
        self.thread.start()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.button = QPushButton('КНОПКА', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(300, 250, 100, 100)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)           # onClicked

    def animation(self):
        self.opacity = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.opacity.setOpacity(0.0)
        self.level2 = QLabel(self)
        self.level2.setText("LABEL")
        self.level2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 100px")
        self.level2.move(450, 250)
        self.level2.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity)
        self.an = QPropertyAnimation(self.opacity, b"opacity")
        self.an.setDuration(2500)
        self.an.setLoopCount(10)
        self.an.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.an.setEndValue(1.0)

    def start(self, _str):
        if not _str:
            self.level2.show()
            self.an.start()
        else: self.level2.hide()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.thread.flagClick = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @AlexanderChernin не совсем понял вашу идею, покажите вашу реализацию в своем ответе.

Comment: Да я сам не понял, поэтому удалил ) Я если честно не очень понимаю, что ему надо )) С одной стороны сигнал `об анимации из потока`, а с другой, в комментарии, `Отправить старт через сигнал, а не ссылку.`

Comment: Поэтому мне кажется, что у вас правильный ответ

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я предположил, что sergeiPython хочет сделать бесконечную анимацию, а не нажимать на кнопку для ее запуска.

Comment: Хм, вполне может быть ) Посмотрим развитие ситуации )

Comment: Вопрос не много не корректный, хотелось что бы клик по кнопке фиксировался в потоке и отправлялся сигнал на старт анимации из потока.

Comment: @sergeiPython добавил обновление попробуйте.